# Transformar função de combinação de resultados em uma função dinamica

Tags: javascript, jquery, lógica

Possuo uma função que gera todas as possíveis combinações de numeros de 1 a 10. As combinações são de 4 números, ou seja, cada combinação tem 4 números diferentes. Ex:

```
[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,6] ... [7,8,9,10];
```

Eu posso especificar o intervalo de números possíveis, que no momento está de 1 a 10.

O meu problema é que eu não posso especificar a quantidade de números que farão a combinação. Que atualmente é 4 para outro número.

Já quebrei a cabeça para tentar deixar a função dinâmica e só passar os parametros(no caso seriam o range de numeros e a quantidade de numeros de uma combinacao), assim:

```
GerarCombinacoes(10, 4); //onde 10 seria o range de numeros de 1 a 10 e 4 a quantidade de numeros da combinacao
```

Minha função está assim no momento:

```
function GerarCombinacoes() {
    totalCombinacoes = 0;
    numeroMaximo = 10; //range de 1 a 10

    for (a = 1; a <= numeroMaximo ; a++) {
        for (b = 2; b <= numeroMaximo ; b++) {
            for (c = 3; c <= numeroMaximo ; c++) {
                for (d = 4; d <= numeroMaximo ; d++) {
                    if ((a != d && a != c && a != b)) {
                        if ((b != d && b != c && b != a) && b > a) {
                            if ((c != d && c != b && c != a) && c > b) {
                                if ((d != c && d != b && d != a) && d > c) {
                                    numeros = a + " - " + b + " - " + c + " - " + d;
                                    totalCombinacoes++;
                                    $("#Numeros").append("<p style='margin-left: 10px'>("+ totalCombinacoes+ ") " + numeros + "</p>");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    alert(totalCombinacoes);
}
```

Se eu quiser aumentar a quantidade de numeros da combinacao eu preciso colocar mais um for e mais uma verificação para não repetir números, mas assim fica complicado pois tem alguns casos que eu precisaria fazer mais de 20 for tudo na mao.

Comment: Só pra entender. Esses ifs são regras da combinação, certo? Tem como passar a regra dessas combinações? Pois no início do post você diz seu script "gera todas as possíveis combinações de números de 1 a 10", mas não é verdade, pois a combinação "1 - 1 - 1 - 1" não entra na sua regra. Passe pra gente a regra da combinação e tentamos ajudar.

Comment: São combinacões diferentes, e com os 4 numeros diferentes entre si. Independente da ordem que apareçam não podem se repetir. Os ifs garantem isso.

Comment: OK e uma outra regra seria não considerar o número zero, certo?

Comment: Exato, na primeira frase da pergunta menciono essas duas informações.

Comment: É que você disse "que no momento está de 1 a 10" e que pelo que entendi você quer uma função genérica, mas beleza. Vou tentar montar uma função pra ajudar também.

Comment: Desculpe. O range sempre será de 1 até o numero que eu definir.

Comment: Sugiro que o pessoal dê uma relembrada em [**combinatória**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria) antes de "se jogar" direto no código - vi algumas soluções que, embora funcionem, são desnecessariamente ineficientes, mesmo levando em conta a ordem de complexidade do problema. (i.e. o número de combinações é `n!/(m!*(n-m)!)` mas vi soluções de ordem de `n^m`, `n^m * log(n^m)` e até `2^n`...)

Comment: P.S. [Não necessariamente](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%281000%2C500%29+%3C+2**1000+%3C+1000**500+%3C+1000**500*log%282%2C+1000*500%29) na [ordem de melhor pra pior...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%281000%2C5%29+%3C+1000**5+%3C+1000**5*log%282%2C+1000*5%29+%3C+2**1000)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse é o tipo de situação que uma solução recursiva seria mais elegante que uma iterativa. Vou sugerir uma implementação bem simples, depois refiná-la para ficar mais flexível e eficiente:

```
function combinacoes(a, b, m, acc, retorno) {
    // acc são os elementos que já fazem parte da combinação
    if ( acc == undefined ) acc = []; // no início, ela começa vazia
    // retorno é a lista de combinações encontradas
    if ( retorno === undefined ) retorno = []; // idem
    if ( m == 0 ) {        // se o número de elementos a serem inseridos chegou a zero
        retorno.push(acc); // coloque a combinação atual na lista
        return retorno;    // e retorne
    }
    if ( a > b )           // se a passou b, não existem mais combinações
        return retorno;    // retorne o que foi achado anteriormente

    // Primeiro fazemos todas as combinações que incluem a
    // i.e. combinamos a com as combinações de tamanho m-1
    combinacoes(a+1, b, m-1, acc.concat([a]), retorno);

    // Depois todas as que não incluem a
    // i.e. ignoramos a, e fazemos as combinações de a+1 pra frente
    return combinacoes(a+1, b, m, acc, retorno);
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/xys9j13b/). O fato da solução ser recursiva não tem impacto na eficiência, pois o número de combinações de n elementos m a m é tão grande (já ouviu a expressão ["explosão combinatória"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)?) que muito antes de você ter problemas de *stack overflow* você vai ter problemas de falta de memória....

Agora vou refiná-la um pouco para não gerar **todas** as combinações de uma vez só; em vez disso, vou criar um "sistema de paginação" onde a função somente gera um subconjunto pequeno dos resultados por vez:

```
// Função auxiliar: quantas combinações existem de n elementos m a m?
// n! / (m! * (n-m)!)
function quantas(n, m) {
    m = ( m < n - m ? m : n - m ); // Para facilitar o cálculo... (pois é simétrico)
    var dividendo = 1;
    var divisor = 1;
    for ( var i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++ ) {
        if ( i <= m )
            divisor *= i;
        if ( n-m < i )
            dividendo *= i;
    }
    return dividendo / divisor;
}

function combinacoes(a, b, m, inicio, fim, acc, retorno) {
    if ( inicio === undefined ) inicio = 0;
    if ( fim === undefined ) fim = quantas(b-a+1, m);
    if ( fim <= 0 )
        return retorno;
    ...
    // Primeiro fazemos todas as combinações que incluem a
    if ( inicio < quantas(b-a, m-1) )
        combinacoes(a+1, b, m-1, inicio, fim, acc.concat([a]), retorno);
    // Depois todas as que não incluem a
    inicio -= quantas(b-a, m-1);
    fim -= quantas(b-a, m-1);
    return combinacoes(a+1, b, m, inicio, fim, acc, retorno);
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/xys9j13b/3/). Experimente com um número "absurdo de grande", como combinações de 1 a 1000, 100 a 100. (Nota: [existem 6.38 × 10^139 resultados](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%281000%2C100%29) - maior do que cabe num `double` - por isso o método acima vai "saltar" alguns resultados... mas a maioria deles vai vir certo)

Comment: @ mgibsonbr, cool! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Esqueça, por um momento, que estamos falando de combinações de números.

Vamos dizer que temos `N` elementos, e que eu quero calcular quantas possibilidades de combinações contendo `M` elementos são possíveis.

Isso é simplesmente cálculo binário.

Eu posso me perguntar de outra maneira: Em `N` bits, eu quero todos os números com `M` bits ligados.

A função para gerar todos os mapas binários das combinações ficaria assim:

```
function GenerateCombinations(totalElements, elementCount) {

    console.debug('Total de elementos: ' + totalElements);
    console.debug('Elementos por combinação: ' + elementCount);

    var res = [];

    for (i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, totalElements); i++) { 

        var probe = i.toString(2).replace(new RegExp('0', 'g'), '');

        if(probe.length == elementCount)
            res.push(i);
    }    

    console.debug(res.length + ' combinações encontradas.');

    return res;
}
```

E, finalmente, a função que realiza a combinação de elementos:

```
function CombineElements(collection, elementCount) {
    var combinations = GenerateCombinations(collection.length, elementCount);

    var res = [];

    for(i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {

        bitmapIndex = combinations[i].toString(2).split("").reverse().join("");
        console.debug(i + ':' + bitmapIndex);
        var arItem = '';

        for(j = 0; j < bitmapIndex.length + 1; j++)
        {
            if (bitmapIndex.substring(j,j+1) == '1')
                arItem += collection[j];
        }

        res.push(arItem);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Alguns exemplos:

Coleções de 2 items entre 4 elementos:

```
CombineElements([1,2,3,4], 2)

Total de elementos: 4  
Elementos por combinação: 2  
6 combinações encontradas.  
["12", "13", "23", "14", "24", "34"]
```

Coleções de 3 items entre 6 elementos:

```
CombineElements([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)

Total de elementos: 6
Elementos por combinação: 3
20 combinações encontradas.
["123", "124", "134", "234", "125", "135", "235", "145", "245", "345", "126", "136", "236", "146", "246", "346", "156", "256", "356", "456"]
```

[Código no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/41n3ksh9/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma função de combinação que permite você usar uma array como entrada de dados:

```js
function combinations( inpSet, qty ) {
  var inpLen = inpSet.length;
  var combi = [];
  var result = []; 
  var recurse = function( left, right ) {
    if ( right == 0 ) {
      result.push( combi.slice(0) );
    } else {
      for ( var i = left; i <= inpLen - right; i++ ) {
        combi.push( inpSet[i] );
        recurse( i + 1, right - 1 );
        combi.pop();
      }
    }
  }
  recurse( 0, qty );
  return result;
}

// Teste:
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(
  combinations( ['a','b','c','d'] , 3 )
);
```

Desta forma, você pode trocar a entrada pelos valores que desejar.

Answer (score 3):

Eu nao sei JS, mas vou explicar uma solucao e mostrar em C++, nao deve ser dificil traduzir.

Uma ressalva: esse tipo de algoritmo tem uma complexidade nojenta e logo logo para de funcionar. Para algo menos pior, voce pode tentar alguma das solucoes [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710713/algorithm-to-generate-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list).

O algoritmo funciona assim:

1. Primeiro a gente precisa de uma estrutura para armazenar as permutacoes. No meu caso vai ser um `set`, uma estrutura do C++ que permite armazenar uma unica copia de cada elemento nele (como um conjunto da matematica).
2. Tambem vamos precisar de outro `set` para guardar a `combinacao atual` que estamos gerando.
3. Agora para o algoritmo em si:

   1. Nos vamos ter uma funcao recursiva que funciona assim: para cada elemento `x` da lista que vai de `1` ate o seu limite `N`, ela tenta inserir `x` em um conjunto que esta armazenando a combinacao ate aqui. Se ela conseguir colocar `x` (o que pode nao acontecer, ja que `x` ja pode estar na combinacao), ela ve se o tamanho total do conjunto e igual ao numero de elementos que voce deseja na combinacao.
   2. Se o tamanho do conjunto for igual, armazene ele no vetor de combinacoes. Se nao for, chame a mesma funcao com o conjunto com o novo elemento.
   3. Quando a chamada recursiva voltar, remove do conjunto o elemento que colocou (no caso `x`).

Quando essa coisa acabar, voce vai ter todas as combinacoes no vetor.

O codigo em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

set< set<int> > combinacoes;

void gen(int limite, unsigned qtos, set<int>& ate_aqui) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= limite; ++i) {
    auto it = ate_aqui.insert(i);
    if (it.second == false) continue;
    if (ate_aqui.size() == qtos)
        combinacoes.insert(ate_aqui);
    else
        gen(limite, qtos, ate_aqui);
    ate_aqui.erase(ate_aqui.find(i));
    }
}

int main() {
    set<int> v;
    gen(4, 3, v);
    for (auto &c : combinacoes) {
        for (auto &x : c) cout << x << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Quando eu rodo isso para com `gen(4, 3, v)`, ou seja, todas as combinacoes de 1 ate 4 com 3 elementos, a saida e:

```
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 3 4 
2 3 4
```

Nao sei se ajuda, mas se nao alguem ja ja posta algo mais especifico para JS.

Comment: Ajuda sim, vou tentar traduzir isso pra JS.

Comment: Aparentemente JS nao tem `sets` XD So encontrei [isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), entao nao sei se e algo util para voce :(

Comment: @LucasVirgili O tipo de dados "conjunto" só estará disponível a partir do EcmaScript6, mas como nesse caso as chaves são numéricas, pode-se simular um conjunto criando um objeto comum tendo os números como propriedades. Ex.: `{1:true, 3:true, 4:true}`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu vi quando dei uma procurada, mas notei que so iria funcionar para numeros e nao para o conjunto de todas as combinacoes.

Comment: @LucasVirgili é verdade, reparei nos conjuntos individuais, mas me esqueci do conjunto de conjuntos... Nesse caso, o *workaround* seria usar strings como chaves: `{"1,3,4":true}`. Mas de fato, estamos em 2014, já está passando da hora de JavaScript ter estruturas de dados decentes... :D

Comment: Achei esquisito nao ter mesmo! Demora pra esse EcmaScript6 sair?

Answer (score 2):

Para gerar todas as combinações possíveis, inclusive com números repetidos, utilize o trecho abaixo. O parâmetro `gama` denota a quantidade de opções para cada célula (ou seja, cada célula será preenchida com um valor de 1 a `gama`). Já `tamanho` representa o comprimento de cada linha do array resultante, ou seja, quantos números de 1 a `gama` devem ser adicionados ao array.

```
function GerarCombinacoes(gama, tamanho){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < Math.pow(gama, tamanho); i++){
        arr[i] = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < tamanho; j++){
            arr[i].push(Math.floor(i / Math.pow(gama, tamanho - j - 1)) % gama + 1);
        }
        arr[i] = arr[i].sort();
    }
    arr = arr.sort();
```

Note que os `sort()` evidenciam as linhas iguais, pois organizam vertical e horizontalmente o array. Adicione um filtro ao array resultante para excluir todas as linhas que possuam elementos repetidos ou que sejam iguais à linha de cima (o que, após o `sort()`, garante que haverá apenas linhas únicas).

```
    arr = arr.filter(function(linha, ind, array){
        var igual_linha_acima = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < linha.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < linha.length; j++){
                if(i != j && linha[i] == linha[j]) return false;
            }
            if(linha[i] != array[ind-1][i]) igual_linha_acima = false;
        }
        if(igual_linha_acima) return false;
        return true;
    });
```

Finalmente, basta retornar o array de combinações resultante.

```
    return arr;
}
```

Qualquer dúvida, é só perguntar que eu detalho mais :)

Edit: editei a resposta para garantir linhas únicas, e [também preparei um JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/eb9b6s3b/).

Comment: +1. Só que notei que as combinacoes se repetem em ordem diferente. Por exemplo: 1,2,3,4 e 4,3,2,1 e 1,3,2,4

Comment: Sort e uniq, @JoaoPaulo :P

Answer (score 0):

Opps, com 3 anos de atraso! uma versão funcional em Python mas facilmente javascriptável:

```
def p(comp,max,pref=[],min=1):
   if comp==0 :
      print(pref)
   else:
      for x in range(min, max-comp+2):
         p(comp-1, max, pref+[x], x+1)

p(3,4)
```